Holonomic drive in Ros2 using Mecanum Wheels
I am working on a robot involving holonomic drive using 4 mecanum wheels. I have the following questions:

Is there any ros2 controller for holonomic drive (like for diff drive and Ackermann Steering Controller at https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/doc/controllers_index.html)?
If not, any idea about how is the robot at the following link https://github.com/MickySukmana/holonomic working(Although it is using omni wheels  and I plan to build a different setup)?

UPDATE_1:
The PR version of ros2 controllers is installed successfully on ros2 iron. I tried publishing command velocities to "/mec_cont/controller_state" topic but the bot is not moving.
To which topic shall I publish command velocities to using teleop_twist_keyboard? The following topics are available when running mecanum drive controller:
/mec_cont/controller_state
/mec_cont/odometry
/mec_cont/reference
/mec_cont/tf_odometry
/mec_cont/transition_event

and in the case of diff_drive controller the following were available out of which I was publishing to "/diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped":
/diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped
/diff_cont/odom
/diff_cont/transition_event

UPDATE_2:
The robot was not performing all the movements involved in a mecanum wheel drive.
I figured out I did not passed "sum_of_robot_center_projection_on_X_Y_axis: 1.0" parameter under "kinematics:" in the controller ".yaml" file. Also make sure the joints are in perfect sequence. Example:
command_joint_names: ["front_left_wheel_joint", "back_left_wheel_joint", "back_right_wheel_joint", "front_right_wheel_joint"]


There is no merged ros2_controller yet in the official repo, but there is a PR for mecanum wheeled robots.

Any idea how to use it?

checkout the branch and compile it from source. You might need the iron-version of ros2_control to get it compiled (both can be compiled on humble distro).

Before working on real hardware, i am trying to get it work on simulation. I have a differential drive bot working fine in gazebo simulation. I uninstalled ros2_control and ros2_controller (installed using binary packages) and the robot was still working fine(Which according to me should not happen as i have uninstalled ros2 control and controllers). Then i uninstalled gazebo-ros2-control and now the bot was not working. I have the following questions:

Could you explain the reason for the same?
If it is because i am working on simulation then would the PR you provided work on gazebo?


You probably can't uninstall ros2_control if you have gazebo_ros2_control installed (it is a direct dependency). Uninstall all, add the iron branches of the three repositories (the branch from the PR, respectively) to your workspace and compile it. Then you have to figure out how to properly configure the mecanuum controller.

I have installed ros2_control from source using commands given at https://control.ros.org/humble/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#building-from-source. Which is working fine. Now to install the Holonomic Drive version of ros2 controller, i am downloading the same file from the site mentioned above using "wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_ci/master/ros_controls.$ROS_DISTRO.repos" and changing the URL at line 36 to "https://github.com/StoglRobotics-forks/ros2_controllers/tree/add-mecanum-drive-controller".

But getting error at "vcs import src < ros_controls.$ROS_DISTRO.repos" line. It is working file with "https://github.com/StoglRobotics-forks/ros2_controllers.git"  link at the line 36 URL but this does not has mecanum wheel drive part as its the master branch. Which link shall i place at line 36?

make your custom repos file and change the url to StoglRobotics-forks and set the correct branch as version, or you use the original repos file, go into the ros2_controllers repo and use gh pr checkout 512 (see the PR i linked, below the Code button)

The PR version of ros2 controller is installed. I tried publishing command velocities to "/mec_cont/controller_state" topic but the bot is not moving. To which topic shall i publish the command velocities? I have updated the question. See the "UPDATE" section for available topics.

Have a look in the userdoc as part of the PR. And you can use ros2cli to see available topics and types (ros2 topic list -t for example

Thanks! It is working now. I am able to move it forward, backward, rotate in left and right direction, but i am unable to make it glide in y axis. I am using a keyboard to control it. Have you used this controller for testing purpose before? Would a joystick be better for this type of movement(glide in y axis)?

I haven't used it. Send a manual composed twist message with y component to test your controller, then think about adapting your input device

I would have to change mecanum controller code?

Please follow tutorials from docs.ros.org or the ros2_control examples like https://control.ros.org/humble/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_2/doc/userdoc.html, there you find information how to send a topic to a node.

I tried publishing y-component manually but the robot ROTATES in that direction INSTEAD of GLIDING.
Dose the shape of wheel has any influence over the controller? I am using normal URDF Cylinder shaped(rotated) wheel instead of actual Mecanum wheel mesh.

For sure. Have a look at the talk Simulation of Highly Dynamic Omnidirectional Robots in Isaac Sim and how much effort they put into simulating mecanum wheels.
